# Confused coordinates - How to start ship expedition?

Tags: anno-2070

So I bought Confused Coordinates ship action/expedition.  I have it loaded onto a warship with some weapons (the thing it says is needed for the action).  How do I start the expedition?
I have tried sailing to the edge of the map, left clicking the item in my storage bay...I dont know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items in cargo slots can't be activated, only ditched into the ocean or transferred to other ship/buildings. You have to move the Coordinates item to one of your ship's 'tool' slots, then activate it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically put the item onto your ship. If the item (Confused Coordinates) is not on the right side (last socket) then Left click it once until it is, then put whatever materials/weapons is needed for the expedition, then Left click the Confused Coordinates one last time and the ship should automatically do the expedition. I am not sure how many materials/weapons you need for the the expedition as I have have 20 or 1 material on the ship and both time I got a reward. So now I just load it up with 1.